# Is there a simple way to merge eclipse features into one eclipse ide of j2ee and modeling

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

i am develop j2ee program using eclipse for j2ee. recently the manager ask us to design using uml(class diagram、sequence diagram) and we are going to use eclipse modeling tools. we want using both j2ee and modeling feature in one eclipse ide. i searched some site and didn't find the solution. does anyone know it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just install the Eclipse Modelling Tools in to your existing Eclipse using 'Help > Install New Software'.

In the install dialog choose your main Eclipse distribution in the 'Work with' combo (for Eclipse Mars that would be `Mars - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars`).

In the tree of available software that appears look in the 'Modelling' section.

[image: Install dialog]

Comment: thx! i got it. furthermore, how can i get the update url (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars) in future eclipse versions.

Comment: The URL is normally already set in each release. The next release will be '.../neon' (should be released in June).

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse it contains no of opensource tools. To get UML diagrams into your eclipse you have to install a plugin called **UML generator in eclipse** by using eclipse market place(HELP --> Eclipse Market Place). You have to follow the common steps to install a plugin in eclipse.

If it will not reach your expectation there is one more plugin is available in eclipse market place called **UML designer**. Try with that.